# Disable RTL direction for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a custom calendar view with `UICollectionView`. Everything is pretty well but when I tried to test when language is set to Arabic, the cells are listed from right to left. Is there a way to disable this in RTL mode. 
I have checked the documentation but there is no such option.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can disable it by setting view semantics property 
You have to set it on UICollectionView
there is a property in UIView Class

```
semanticContentAttribute
```

with following value

```
UISemanticContentAttributeUnspecified = 0,
UISemanticContentAttributePlayback, 
UISemanticContentAttributeSpatial, 
UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight,
UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft
```

[image]

Comment: @swiftnub I have updated my answer for setting this property by code.

Comment: @MuhammadImran do you know how to do the same but in iOS 8? as this is only avialable in iOS 9

Comment: @HossamGhareeb if you're still looking something like this can be done as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Answer (score 0):

To Disable RTL on specific view in Swift 4.

```
myView.semanticContentAttribute = .unspecified
```